# Edit text value in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a **text** column which holds a json with very long values - actually HTML code.

```
{"first_key" : "a very long html", "second_key" : "another very long html"}
```

How can I easily delete the second_key and its vale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regex_replace`, and hope that the second html doesn't contain a `}` character:

```
update MY_TABLE set text_column = regex_replace(text_column, ', "second_key": ".*\}"', '')
where my_column_id = '<whatever>';
```

You will have to tweak your regex to make this work. You can test it by doing a `select` with the same expression to see what you get.